# Confidence interval of least square estimator and dependence of parameters

Tags: confidence-interval, least-squares, curve-fitting

I have data from a physics experiment, where we measure some quantity $y$ as a function of $x$ and $t$. In practice, I have access to $M$ values $x_i$ of $x$, $N$ values $t_j$ of $t$, and thus $M\times N$ values $y_{i,j}$ of $y$.

I also have a model that predicts that $y(x,t)= t^a f(x t^b)$, where I do not know the parameters $a$, $b$ and the ``scaling function'' $f(z)$ (whatever that physics jargon means).

While I don't care too much about $f$ itself (beyond the fact that there is such a function that describes my data), I really want to find $a$ and $b$. In particular, my theory also predicts that $a$ and $b$ are not independent and should obey some relation (say $a=\alpha b$ with a prediction that $\alpha=2$). What I would like is a method that allows me to find $a$ and $b$, with some confidence interval, and also a way to assert how much the relation between them is fulfilled (say by having some confidence interval on $\alpha$ too).

Here is what I do right now: I compute a least-square estimator of the form
$$
R^2(a,b)=\sum_{i,j}\left( y_{i,j}-t_j^{a}\bar f(x_i t_j^{b})\right)^2,
$$
where $\bar f(z)$ is estimated by binning $x_i t_j^{b}$ (for a given $b$), taking the average in each bin and then interpolating to obtain a function of $z$. It thus depends on $b$.

Plotting $R^2$ gives the kind of colorplot shown below (here the labels $s$ and $\nu$ are related to $a$ and $b$), and we clearly see that close to the minimum (green dot), the constant levels of $R^2$ are ellipsoidal (the magenta dot corresponds to some theoretical predictions, but this is not important here). The fact that the major axis is along the direction (1,2) and the minor axis along $(2,-1)$ seems to indicate to me that the two parameters are not independent but are related in good approximation by $s=2\nu$.

My questions are: how do I compute the confidence interval of these two parameters, and how do I quantify how much they are correlated?
[image]